# How to defer a test server closure when doing parallel table test cases?

Tags: go, testing, synchronization

I’m having a trouble deferring the closure of a test http server when doing parallel table test funcs. I’m trying waiting using a `sync.WaitGroup` but the `wg.Done()` is either closing too early, or never happening.

```golang
ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    _, _ = w.Write([]byte(`hello`))
}))
defer ts.Close()

var wg sync.WaitGroup
for _, tc := range testCases {
    wg.Add(1)
    func(tc testCase) {
        // `Done` here doesn't wait for the test to run, so closes the test server early
        // defer wg.Done()
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            // `Done` here is never called, so causes a timeout
            // defer wg.Done()
            t.Parallel()
            _, err := http.Get(ts.URL)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err.Error())
            }
        })
    }(tc)
}
wg.Wait()
```

For runnable example please see https://play.golang.org/p/1GvWRwlrsjA

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely because `t.Run()` doesn't block if `t.Parallel()` is used inside its body. Wrapping `t.Parallel()` test cases into non-parallel group should resolve it:

```golang
...
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for _, tc := range testCases {                                                                                                                                   
    wg.Add(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    func(tc testCase) {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        defer wg.Done()                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        t.Run("mygroup", func(t *testing.T) {                                                                                                                                                                                   
            t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {                                                                                                                                                                                    
                t.Parallel()                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                _, err := http.Get(ts.URL)
                if err != nil {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                    t.Fatal(err.Error())                                                                                                                                                                                          
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            })                                                                                                                                                                                                            
         })                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    }(tc)
}
wg.Wait()
...
```

EDIT: I found this reference in Golang repo Issues which suggests same: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17791

Comment: Interesting thread, thank you! For now I've solved it differently, but this is a valuable piece of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

If you have go 1.14 or later I recommend you use `T.Cleanup` for cleanup tasks after tests. Additionally is there any reason you dont want a new server for each subtest? Using a shared server means you lose subtest isolation .

> Cleanup registers a function to be called when the test and all its
> subtests complete. Cleanup functions will be called in last added,
> first called order.

https://godoc.org/testing#T.Cleanup

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. The reason I didn't have the test server on each subtest is because I thought I needed the url to instantiate my http client (cannot be done in parallel, still a WIP), but I've looked in more detail, I see I can move the ts inside, so problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use `T.Cleanup()`.

[From official go documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Cleanup)

> Cleanup registers a function to be called when the test (or subtest) and all its subtests complete. Cleanup functions will be called in last added, first called order.

As an example:

```
t.Cleanup(func() {
    db.Close()
    server.Close()
    engine.Shutdown()
    // Some more code ...
})
```